# site is super slow GET customer/section/load/?sections=cart&force_new_section_timestamp=false&_=xxxxxx

Tags: magento2, extensions, debug, slow-response

My site became super slow since yesterday. I can not find out which extension causes this. I thought it might because of the weltpixel Google Tag Manager, i disabled it. 
Run

```
setup:upgrade; 
setup di:compile; 
s:s:d
```

but the site is still very slow.

> this is the request that makes the site so slow
>
> https://www.example.com/customer/section/load/?sections=cart&force_new_section_timestamp=false&_=xxxxxxxx

[image]

```
response
    {"cart":{"summary_count":0,"subtotalAmount":null,"subtotal":"<span class=\"price\">$0.00<\/span>","possible_onepage_checkout":true,"items":[],"extra_actions":" <div data-mage-init='{\"Magento_Paypal\\\/js\\\/in-context\\\/button\":{\"id\":\"paypal-express-in-context-mini-cart\",\"linkDataAction\":\"paypal-in-context-checkout\",\"paypalButton\":\"paypal-express-in-context-checkout-main\",\"addToCartSelector\":\"\"}}' class=\"paypal checkout paypal-logo paypal-express-in-context-mini-cart-container\"><a data-action=\"paypal-in-context-checkout\" href=\"#\"><img class=\"paypal-button-hidden\" src=\"https:\/\/www.paypalobjects.com\/webstatic\/en_US\/i\/buttons\/checkout-logo-medium.png\" alt=\"Check out with PayPal\" \/><\/a><\/div>  <div data-label=\"or\" class=\"paypal checkout  after paypal-logo ec_shortcut_bml_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\" data-mage-init='{ \"paypalCheckout\": { \"isCatalogProduct\": \"\", \"shortcutContainerClass\": \".ec_shortcut_bml_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\" } }' ><input type=\"image\" data-action=\"checkout-form-submit\" data-checkout-url=\"https:\/\/www.gofanco.com\/paypal\/bml\/start\/button\/1\/\" src=\"https:\/\/www.paypalobjects.com\/webstatic\/en_US\/i\/buttons\/ppcredit-logo-medium.png\" alt=\"Checkout with PayPal\" title=\"Checkout with PayPal\"\/>  <a href=\"https:\/\/www.securecheckout.billmelater.com\/paycapture-content\/fetch?hash=AU826TU8&amp;content=\/bmlweb\/ppwpsiw.html\"><img src=\"https:\/\/www.paypalobjects.com\/webstatic\/en_US\/btn\/btn_bml_text.png\" \/><\/a> <\/div> <div id=\"minicart-amazon-pay-button\" class=\"amazon-minicart-container\"><div class=\"amazon-button-container\"><div class=\"amazon-button-container__cell\"><div id=\"PayWithAmazon-shortcutbuttons-0\" class=\"login-with-amazon\" data-mage-init='{\"Amazon_Payment\\\/js\\\/amazon-button\":{\"buttonType\":\"PwA\"}}'><\/div><\/div><div class=\"amazon-button-container__cell\"><div class=\"field-tooltip toggle\"><span class=\"field-tooltip-action action-help\" data-mage-init='{\"dropdown\":{\"activeClass\":\"_active\"}}' data-toggle=\"dropdown\" aria-haspopup=\"true\" aria-expanded=\"false\"><\/span> <div class=\"field-tooltip-content\" data-target=\"dropdown\" aria-hidden=\"true\">Are you an Amazon customer? Pay now with address and payment details stored in your Amazon account.<\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div>","isGuestCheckoutAllowed":true,"website_id":"1","storeId":"1","amazon_quote_has_excluded_item":false,"subtotal_incl_tax":"<span class=\"price\">$0.00<\/span>","subtotal_excl_tax":"<span class=\"price\">$0.00<\/span>","data_id":1571424976}}
```

Comment: the caches enabled? deployment mode is production? what custom modules/logic/layout overrides you've affecting the customer section

Comment: cache is enabled, and yes, in production mode.

Comment: seems related to ultimo somehow, hard to tell without code checking but why not to try looking for `force_new_section_timestamp` in the code and see. If I could find any project that uses ultimo will back to you

Comment: thank you @M.Elwan

Comment: i updated the question with the response. by the way, yes, i'm using ultimo theme, magento 2.2.9. Thank you